# How to set options on INLINE EVENTS in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have this element:

```
<div ontouchmove="myfunc(event)">...</div>
```

How can I set the options for inline events like on addEventListener:

```
element.addEventListener('touchmove', myfunc, { passive: false });
//... { passive: false } is the option
```

- if **event listeners** are better than **inline events** isnot the point of my question. My question is simple: how to set the options for inline events

Comment: you don't......

Comment: hence why event listeners are better than inline events. ;)

Comment: lol, thank you! XD